# Coordinating Conjunction

Tags: punctuation

Could you please give advice on whether a comma is needed before the *and* in the following  sentence?  And if it is, why?

> This autistic dance group has made history at the European
>   championships, and now they want to change the way we all see young
>   people with autism.

Comment: That the "authority" in the link can’t tell the difference between a compound sentence and a compound verb doesn't add weight to its opinions.

Comment: @KarlG 'That the "authority" in the link can’t tell the difference between a compound sentence and a compound verb doesn't add weight to its opinions.' Would you care to spell that out?  'He left the house and then he went home.' is a compound sentence where the independent clauses have the same subject. 'John left the house, and then Jill followed.'  is a compound sentence where the independent clauses have different subjects. A compound verb is for example 'kick-start' or 'blow-dry'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: compound predicate then. He bought a new car and drive it home.

Comment: @KarlG Your erroneous comment comes across as being a dire example  of hypocrisy. I suggest you delete it.

Answer (score -1):

You could write:

> This autistic dance group has made history at the European championships. Now they want to change the way we all see young people with autism.

This hasn't altered the meaning of the sentence. By combining the two sentences into one sentence with your conjunction, the comma can be seen as politeness to your reader, as expecting them to read:

> This autistic dance group has made history at the European championships and now they want to change the way we all see young people with autism.

can be seen as a bit of a challenge!

Comment: Would  you say a comma is optional  or mandatory in the sentence?

Comment: @Goldenboy12; the sentence itself isn't mandatory, so the comma can't be. I personally would use a comma. Or two sentences, but not one long sentence.